# NoMethodError in Users#show

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, route, path-separator

Estou aprendendo Rails, seguindo um livro que possui o seguinte código:

#### UserController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def new
   @user = User.new
 end

 def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def show
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end

 def create
   @user = User.new(params[:user])
   if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, :notice => 'Cadastro realizado'

   else
     render :new
   end
  end      
end
```

#### show.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%=notice%></p>

<h2>Perfil: <%=@user.full_name %></h2>

    <ul>
        <li>Localização: <%= @user.location %> </li>
        <li>Bio: <%= @user.bio %></li>
   </ul>

   <%= link_to 'Editar Perfil', edit_user_path(@user) %>
   <%= link_to 'Mostrar Perfil', show_user_path(@user) %>
```

Na verdade o livro só vai até o código `edit_user_path`, porém eu quis fazer uns testes e não estou entendendo porque quando uso o s`how_user_path` ele diz que o método não existe ao invés de retornar o mesmo usuário, ao trocar por apenas

```
<%= link_to 'Mostrar Perfil', @user %>
```

o código funciona, mas eu gostaria de saber o porque com o `show_user_path` ele retorna um erro sendo que o método obviamente existe no *controller*, meu objetivo seria mostrar o perfil que foi criado.

Comment: Qual é a exata mensagem de erro? (incluindo o arquivo e a linha)

Comment: Mas você quer mostrar o perfil a partir de qual view? Você não usou scaffold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um comando que auxilia na visualização de suas `routes`. Quando você acessa uma URL como `/users/1/edit`, usando `edit_user_path`, ele te redireciona para a action `edit` do seu `users_controller`.
Esse comando é o `rake routes`. Executando ele na linha de comando na pasta base do seu projeto você vai ver que a rota que redireciona para a ação `show` é diferente de `show_user_path`.

```
new_user GET users#new
edit_user GET users#edit
user GET users#show
```

Como pode ver, usando `user_path(@user)` irá usar a rota correta.

Answer (score 0):

Como você está aprendendo agora, é bom começar assim escrevendo o código na "unha" e entendendo. Mas tem um comando chamado scaffold, ele gera um [CRUD](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) básico apartir de apenas uma linha de comando.

Exemplo:

```
rails generate scaffold user nome:string idade:integer
```

(rails g scaffold nome_do_model atributo:tipo)

Comment: Eu sei do scaffold, isso é pra aprendizado, gostaria de saber porque um edit_user_path funciona, mas um show_user_path me retorna um erro, por dedução achei que a ação seria nomedaação_user_path

Comment: Mas você esta usando esse path dentro de qual view?

Comment: Dentro da show.html.erb em apps/users/views

Comment: Mas você quer show dentro de show? Meio sem lógica... Mas você que da show em que? Qual usuario? Creio que esta dando erro porque você ja está dentro de Show

Comment: Sim, não é pra ter lógica, é pra aprender mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Para ver todas as rotas que você tem, você pode ir no navegar e colocar o seguinte endereço: http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes

Você verá que terá algumas rotas diferentes, exemplos:

index:

```
users_path
```

new:

```
new_user_path
```

edit:

```
edit_user_path
```

- é necessário passar o parâmetro (id)

e as demais (show, update e destroy):

```
user_path
```

- é necessário passar o parâmetro (id) e também o metódo (GET para show, PATCH/PUT para update, DELETE para destroy)

Para o **SHOW** ficaria dessa forma:

```
<%= link_to 'Mostrar Perfil', user_path(@user) %>
```

Para o **DESTROY** ficaria dessa forma:

```
<%= link_to 'Mostrar Perfil', user_path(@user), method: 'delete' %>
```

No caso do **UPDATE** você irá fazer isso no controller, recebendo os parâmetros da action **EDIT**. Não será necessário especificar o método :D